# How to generate an iOS IPA file with Ionic Framework?

Tags: ios, cordova, build, ionic-framework, ipa

I've successfully built the iOS app with the `ionic build ios` command. But now I want to use [TestFlight](https://www.testflightapp.com/) and it asks me for an IPA file. It seems that file is not generated with that build command. So, how can I generate it?

Thanks

Answer (score 38):

You can easily build IPA from ionic framework. by following these steps

1. Navigate to app folder

[image: OS X terminal with list command]

2. Run cordova build command

[image: OS X terminal running ionic build command]

3. Open the Xcode Project

[image: OS X Finder with project location]

4. Clean the project

[image: XCode Product -> Clean menu]

5. Select iOS mobile device to build for, don't use iOS emulator as device otherwise the archive is disabled.

[image: Xcode Target device selected]

6. Archive the project

[image: Xcode Project -> Archive menu]

7. Distribute the project

[image: XCode Organizer]

8. Choose a method for distribution

[image: Selecting method for distribution]

9. Choose a Profile

[image: Choosing a profile]

10. Select a location to save the .ipa file

[image: Saving IPA file to Desktop folder]

I have generate my .ipa file by using these steps hope it will works for your's.

Comment: You need to have the correct provisioning profiles setup in order to run the archive command. Perhaps you could mention/link this.

Comment: @roshan-bharti this steps works with Ionic 2? ,because I don't have enable the  `archive` option

Comment: @CristianChaparroA. yes it works. Check out step 5 - by selecting Generic iOS Device the archive option will be enabled

Comment: Is it possible to generate an unsigned ipa? Someone else is going to publish the application and they require an unsigned ipa and apk from me. Android is easy but I have no idea if you can even build ipa without signing.

Answer (score 6):

[this article](http://www.splinter.com.au/xcode-4-command-line-builds-of-iphone-apps/) is kind of old but should help you.

In Command line change into the folder that contains your *.xcodeproj, and run the following:

```
xcodebuild -target "My Target" -scheme "My Scheme"
-configuration Release clean archive
```

Now you’ve got your xcarchive , Following line will generate ipa which you can upload to TestFlight.

```
cd platforms/ios/build/device/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication "$(pwd)/$PROJECT_NAME.app" -o "$(pwd)/$PROJECT_NAME.ipa"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: is it possible to do this from my ubuntu.. I try to do ```ionic build ios``` but it gives me an error. Is this solution only for macs?

Comment: I am getting stuck between step 6 and step 7.
I select Product > Archive, and I get "Build succeeded".
I then cannot find a list of archives.

Comment: @Bhumit, I am new to IONIC. Is above commands still works for IONIC3?? I am looking for sequence of command to generate ipa using terminal. Thanks in advance.

Comment: see new command for PackageApplication https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094380/whats-the-replacement-for-xcodes-packageapplication#43116435

Answer (score 1):

What I do is to run this command:

```
ionic cordova run ios
```

It will build and make the project, generate the IPA and then launch the simulator. At that moment I just quit the simulator and voila! I have my IPA  with just one command (Ionic 4).

Comment: what is the path where .ipa file is?

Comment: It should be under platform/ios/build... but I was just.a newbie when I posted that comment. I do know now that building an IPA that is actually usable on other devices its a much more complex task.

Answer (score 0):

Use `npx ionic build ios --device` to build the IPA for debugging and adhoc installations

Use `npx ionic build ios --device --release` to build for release.

You need to have a `build.json` file to specify your keys.  Note the CLANG is to prevent compilation errors from the CocoaPods which they made into an error rather than a warning from before.

```json
{
  "ios": {
    "debug": {
      "buildFlag": [
        "CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER = YES"
      ],
      "developmentTeam": "XXXXXX",
      "automaticProvisioning": true,
      "packageType": "development"
    },
    "release": {
      "buildFlag": [
        "CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER = YES"
      ],
      "codeSignIdentity": "Apple Development",
      "developmentTeam": "XXXXXX",
      "automaticProvisioning": true,
      "packageType": "app-store"
    }
  }
}
```

Before it will upload to AppStore/TestFlight you need to modify the platform/ios/exportOptions.plist file to include

```xml
<key>destination</key>
<string>upload</string>
```

Then deploy it to the AppStore as follows

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath "platforms/ios/myApp.xcarchive" \
  -allowProvisioningUpdates \
  -exportOptionsPlist platforms/ios/exportOptions.plist \
  -exportPath platforms/ios/build/device
```