# How to generate IOS .IPA file using cordova command

Tags: ios, cordova, ipa

Hello i am new to iphone app developement.I am using cordova command line to build the ios app.Need to generate the ipa file for deployment into apple store.However i didn't find any suitable answer for my question .Please help me out.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have mac follow the steps use this link

https://nickalchemist.wordpress.com/2012/07/04/installing-iphone-apps-without-a-mac-using-apple-developer-account-and-phonegap-build-3/

or

[How to generate an iOS IPA file with Ionic Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919449/how-to-generate-an-ios-ipa-file-with-ionic-framework)

may be this link help you out

Comment: I have a mac .How to generate IPA in mac with out the xcode ?

Comment: having a mac but don't having Xcode similar to don't having mac so plz first try the this link  https://nickalchemist.wordpress.com/2012/07/04/installing-iphone-apps-without-a-mac-using-apple-developer-account-and-phonegap-build-3/

Comment: use this command :-      cordova build ios --device
cd platforms/ios/build/device
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication "$(pwd)/$PROJECT_NAME.app" -o "$(pwd)/$PROJECT_NAME.ipa"