# Unable to find generated .ipa location in Xcode 9.1

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, ionic2, xcode8

Brief explanation - I am trying to create `.ipa` from my Xcode project by clicking on `Product > Build`

When I do this, it says **Build Succeeded**.

But the problem is, I am unable to locate the `.ipa` generated.

I have found all locations but still I am unable to find it.

Comment: Try `Product` > `archive`

Comment: You can refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919449/how-to-generate-an-ios-ipa-file-with-ionic-framework/32857944#32857944

Comment: when i click on archive, it says build failed , when i click on build, its says build succeded..there is nothing in archive

Comment: Strange because, I generate `.ipa` through `Product > archive`. Try to refer above link.