# Can we built Ionic app in windows and just send that to iPhone and install and run?

Tags: ios, macos, ionic-framework, ionic3

Well, I am developing an ionic app in windows 10..can I built that app in my windows pc and then send that app to iPhone or iPad and install and run that app...Is there any must and should need of MAC to build the .ipa or ipsw.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, No you cannot.

All you can do is, code and then run `cordova build ios` which will export an xcode project.

To compile this, you will need a mac with proper xcode installed, a developer account certificate and provision profile to run on a real device.

If you are free-lancer **DO NOT** share this xcode-project build until you are fully paid up ;)

Comment: I found one more same question regarding this, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919449/how-to-generate-an-ios-ipa-file-with-ionic-framework

Comment: They have explained very well.