# How to generate ipa file in Xcode 10

Tags: ios, ionic3

I am new to Xcode.i want to generate .ipa file for my ionic project, I have MacBook and Apple ID . how can I generate ipa file using Xcode 10. Is it necessary to enroll in apple developers account for $99 .

[image: In Xcode 10 options are different like below]

[image: After selecting the development it is showing like not enrolled ,what does it mean]

Comment: Please refer the same question earlier :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919449/how-to-generate-an-ios-ipa-file-with-ionic-framework

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate an iOS IPA file with Ionic Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919449/how-to-generate-an-ios-ipa-file-with-ionic-framework)

Comment: Just now I edited my question please check once it is different

Comment: thanks Faysal Ahmed you saved my day.

Comment: @Steve I just added an answer. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, it is necessary to enroll in Apple developers account for $99. Without this IPA will not generate.

**Another interesting thing:** You can try this to export ipa file from XCode without a developer account. This ipa only for testing I think not for release.

https://medium.com/m%CE%BBgn%CE%BEt%CE%BBr/how-to-export-a-ipa-file-from-xcode-without-a-dev-account-bac8b2645ad3

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have an Apple developer account in order to generate the .ipa. Once you generate the ipa you can use this page https://www.diawi.com/ to distribute your app.

Comment: I'm not able to generate the ipa file please suggest me how to generate the ipa. Is it necessary to buy apple developer account to generate ipa file

Comment: If you need to have an Apple developer account in order to generate the .ipa.